# Expanding Div width to Screen Width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having a problem related to resonsive themes. **I am having a DIV which has a size of 30%(300px original width)**. Now I want **that div to be expanded to screen width that is 500px**. I tried a lot of but didn't help.

Could anyone help me to find a solution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Expand when? If the screen 500px?

Comment: What... 300px is 30% and 500px is 100% (screen width, as you pointed)? Seems to be illogically... And, ah, you tried a lot? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try to use

```
width: 30%;
min-width: 500px;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c6dgsu71/

```
#myOriginalDiv300wth{
    width:30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #myOriginalDiv300wth {
    width: auto;  // Or use 100% or 500px here....
  }
}
```